# What sets do convex sets generate in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

Intuitively, it's possible to decompose most of the bounded connected set I can think of into a union and intersection of convex sets: stretch a rubber band around it, and it gives the convex hull. Then we get smaller and simpler shapes that needs to be cut away from the hull, repeat.

Of course, any set is a union of uncountably many singletons, but if we confine to **finite** union and intersection of convex sets, it seems more interesting.

So, is there a simply characterization of sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that can be generated by finite union and intersection of convex sets?

Comment: Look up the Jordan measure. Essentially these sets are called the Jordan measurable sets and underlie the basis of the Riemann integrability

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by simple? Being finite union of convex sets isn't simple!

Comment: BTW, when you say finite union of convex sets,  you can drop the word intersection.